# Can't see data in Kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have installed elasticsearch 1.7, logstash, redis, nginx and kiabana 4 on different machines. All of them are working perfectly except kibana 4.

When I add index in kibana 4, it gets added but I **can't see any data** inside that index.

Any help here?

Comment: Check that you have data in your ES node/cluster, also check that the date field has correct values and that your date range in Kibana is querying a relevant time frame. For example, you have 1000 documents but all dated to last year when the default Kibana time frame is last 15 minutes.

Comment: check this URL : http://localhost:5601/status. Replace localhost with your ip address.