# Unable to see data in Kibana 4 on Ubuntu

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am trying to visualize my data file using Kibana

The format of my file is as follows

```
timeStamp;elapsed;label;responseCode;responseMessage;threadName;success;failureMessage;bytes;grpThreads;allThreads;Latency;SampleCount;ErrorCount;Hostname
2016-01-16 02:27:17,565;912;HTTP Request;200;OK;Thread Group 1-5;true;;78854;10;10;384;1;0;sundeep-Latitude-E6440    timeStamp;elapsed;label;responseCode;responseMessage;threadName;success;failureMessage;bytes;grpThreads;allThreads;Latency;SampleCount;ErrorCount;Hostname
2016-01-16 02:27:17,565;912;HTTP Request;200;OK;Thread Group 1-5;true;;78854;10;10;384;1;0;sundeep-Latitude-E6440
```

To map the above data, my logstash config is as follows:

```
input { 
  file {
    path => [ "/home/sundeep/data/test.csv"]
    start_position => "beginning"  
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"  
  }
}
filter {
  if ([message] =~ "responseCode") {
    drop { }
  } else {
    csv {
    separator => ";"
        columns => ["timeStamp", "elapsed", "label", "responseCode","responseMessage","threadName",
                "success","failureMessage", "bytes", "grpThreads", "allThreads", "Latency",
                "SampleCount", "ErrorCount", "Hostname"]
   }

  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "aa-%{+yyyy-MM-dd}"
  }
}
```

The template file is as follows:

```
{
"template": "aa-*",
"settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "index.refresh_interval": "5s"
},
"mappings": {
    "logs": {
        "properties": {
            "timeStamp": {
              "index": "analyzed",
      "type": "date",
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"
            },
            "elapsed": {
                "type": "long"
            },
             "dummyfield": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "label": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "responseCode": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "threadName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "success": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "failureMessage":{
                "type": "string"
            },
            "bytes": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "grpThreads": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "allThreads": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "Latency": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "SampleCount": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "ErrorCount": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "Hostname": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Now as you can see, a new index is created in elasticsearch as soon  as I start logstash with the config file.

[image: Elastic search Index List]

The newly created index starts from aa-* which is expected.

Now, I search for the Index in Kibana and I can see it as below:

[[image: New Index in Kibana[2]]

However, I cannot see any data when I try to plot a line chart.

- Things which I have tried:

  1. Deleting the index from Sense and then creating again via sense (did not work)
  2. Changing Timestamp of Log file, did not work as import was successful
  3. Tried the Solution here [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808891/cant-see-data-in-kibana-4)

Also, I was able to visualize another dataset, from this blog post:[enter link description here](http://blog.webkid.io/visualize-datasets-with-elk/)

Trace log:

[2016-01-16 02:45:41,105][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Hulk 2099] [aa-2016-01-15] deleting index
[2016-01-16 02:46:01,370][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Hulk 2099] [aa-2016-01-15] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], templates [aa], shards [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao1hf.png)/[0], mappings [logs]
[2016-01-16 02:46:01,451][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Hulk 2099] [aa-2016-01-15] update_mapping [logs]

ELK Stack
ElasticSearch - 2.1
Logstash - 2.1
Kibana - 4.3.1.1

Comment: A common issue is that kibana, by default, is only looking back 15 minutes.  (Though that may not be your issue since you're not using the date{} filter yet).

Comment: Yes Alain, I tried the 5 year filter too with no luck

Comment: Install a plugin like elasticsearch-head that will allow you to browse the documents in the index.  Or curl from the index and see what's there.

Comment: @AlainCollins : I added the elasticheadplugin, I finally got it to work, after changing the column - timeStamp in the file